# How to set Locale before login in vmware api call for Non English vCenter

Tags: python, vmware, suds, vmware-sdk

I am using VMware API to perform vCenter operation. Used suds to make SDK call. My vCenter is configure for Non English (Japanese) support.

```
import suds

client = suds.client.Client("http://localhost/sdk/vimService.wsdl", location="https://localhost/sdk")

mo = suds.sudsobject.Property("ServiceInstance")
mo._type = "ServiceInstance"
service_content = client.service.RetrieveServiceContent(mo)

try:
    client.service.Login(service_content.sessionManager, username='test', password='test', locale='en_US')
    var = client.factory.create('ns0:WaitOptions')
    kwargs = {'maxWaitSeconds': "2", 'maxObjectUpdates': "3"} 
    [setattr(var, key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items()] 
    client.service.WaitForUpdatesEx(service_content.propertyCollector, version=1, options=var)
except suds.WebFault as e:
    print e.args
```

If I will not set `locale`, then is there any error occur in vCenter, it will return you in Non English text. I set `locale` and exception will be return in **English** language.

We set a `locale` and its working fine with `session` created but if is there any error in Session creation or session is timed out, then it gives error in Non English form.

Please check this code (Call method without create `session`)

```
...
...
mo._type = "ServiceInstance"
service_content = client.service.RetrieveServiceContent(mo)

try:
    var = client.factory.create('ns0:WaitOptions')
    kwargs = {'maxWaitSeconds': "2", 'maxObjectUpdates': "3"} 
    [setattr(var, key, value) for key, value in kwargs.items()] 
    client.service.WaitForUpdatesEx(service_content.propertyCollector, version=1, options=var)
except suds.WebFault as e:
    print e.args
```

Output :

```
(u"Server raised fault: '\u30bb\u30c3\u30b7\u30e7\u30f3\u304c\u8a8d\u8a3c\u3055\u308c\u3066\u3044\u307e\u305b\u3093\u3002'",)
```

Translation :

```
(u"Server raised fault: 'セッションが認証されていません。'",)
# English
(u"Server raised fault: 'Session is not authenticated.',)
```

Is there any way to set `locale` in wsdl url like **`http://localhost/sdk/vimService.wsdl?local=en_US`**?

Comment: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2056635 this may be useful

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар I am not getting error on setting locale. I need to set locale without session. Please see updated question.